# How to iteratively display the nth derivative?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, display

I am new to Mathematica, but not so new to programming. What I'd like to do in Mathematica (not using an API) is to display on each line, the nth derivative of a function, e.g. for n = 1..10. Is there a way to accomplish this in Mathematica? (without explicitly typing the command for each derivative of course. e.g. does Mathematica have iterative constructs to do this).

Comment: `Column[D[Sin[x] Log[x], {x, #}] & /@ Range[10]]` ?

Comment: @b.gatessucks looks good; how about: `Print@D[Sin[x] Log[x], {x, #}] & ~Array~ 10;` ?

Comment: ...or `Scan[Print[D[Sin[x] Log[x], {x, #}]] &, Range[10]]` or `Do[Print[D[Sin[x] Log[x], {x, k}]], {k, 10}]`.

Comment: @J.M. not enough infix. :^)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, but I am forced to *think* when reading infix... ;)

Comment: @J.M. I know the feeling :)

Comment: `NestList[D[#, x] &, {f[x], Exp[-a*x]}, 10] // Grid`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoiding cleverness as much as possible, you can just use a `Do` loop:

```
Do[Print[D[Exp[-a*x], {x, n}]], {n, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or for example

```
Grid@(List@D[Exp[-a*x], {x, #}] & /@ Range[0, 10])
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

etc

Answer (score 2):

"Iteratively differentiate" cries out `Nest[]` to me,....

```
Print /@ NestList[D[#, x] &, Exp[-a*x], 10];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or substitute `CellPrint@ExpressionCell[#, "Output"] &` for `Print` for different styling.